# AWS-CloudWatch: InvalidSequenceTokenException

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a php worker where i log events to AWS could watch.
Unfortunately i got the following error when i try to submit it.

> InvalidSequenceTokenException Error executing "PutLogEvents" on
>   "https://logs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error:
>   `POST https://logs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad
>   Request` response:
>   {"__type":"InvalidSequenceTokenException","expectedSequenceToken":"999999999999990356407851919528174
>   (truncated...)  InvalidSequenceTokenException (client): The given
>   sequenceToken is invalid. The next expected sequenceToken is:
>   495599999999988500356407851919528174642 -
>   {"__type":"InvalidSequenceTokenException","expectedSequenceToken":"495573099999999900356407851919528174642","message":"The
>   given sequenceToken is invalid. The next expected sequenceToken is:
>   495579999999900356407851919528174642"}

and this is my code

```
 $date = new DateTime();
 $instance= = new CloudWatchLogsClient([
                'region' => 'eu-west-1',
                'version' => 'latest',
                'credentials' => [
                    'key' => 'XXX',
                    'secret' => 'XXXX'
                ]
            ]);
        $instance->putLogEvents([
                'logGroupName' => "WorkerLog",
                'logStreamName' => "log",
                'logEvents' => [
                    [
                        'timestamp' => $date->getTimestamp(),
                        'message' => "test log"
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html

You must include a sequence token with your request. If you don't have one you must use describeLogStreams (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeLogStreams.html) to get the stream sequence.

When you make a call to putLogEvents you will get the nextToken in the response. You also must be ready for the case in which someone else pushes to the stream and invalidates the nextToken. (in this case you need to describe the stream again to get an updated token).

Comment: Thanks you are right. But calling describeLogStream will not return the nextsequencetoken!. Please update your answer so i can accept it.

Comment: actually it does. I you look a the response, it contains an array of LogStreams object: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_LogStream.html The UploadSequenceToken in the response is what you need to pass in.

Comment: is there a simpler way to get the `nextSequenceToken` besides calling `describeLogStreams` (describeLogStream singular does not seem to exist)?

Comment: @AlexanderMills not that i'm aware of. the pattern is that you putEvents and with each event you get the next token. So as long as your code is the only entity putting Events you will always know the nextToken (and the usage of describe is limited). If you have multiple entities pushing events that when things get interesting. you could always use multiple streams to minimize contention, but you still have to solve this issue

Comment: In the API document, it is said that for the exception shown, we may get the sequenceToken in the field `expectedSequenceToken`. Would that be a better approach?

Answer (score 5):

The `DescribeLogStreams` does not support the same volume call as `PutLogEvent`. You may got throttled if calling it frequently.

The recommended way to do it is calling the `PutLogEvents` directly and catch the `InvalidSequenceTokenException`. Then retry the `PutLogEvents` with Sequence Token in the `InvalidSequenceTokenException` message.

Correct sequence token can be found in the [expectedSequenceToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html#API_PutLogEvents_Errors) field of `InvalidSequenceTokenException`

```php
    try {
        $result = $client->describeLogStreams([
            'logGroupName' => $logGroupName,
            'logStreamNamePrefix' => $logStreamName,
        ]);

        $uploadSequenceToken = $logStreams[0]['uploadSequenceToken'];

        $client->putLogEvents([
            'logGroupName' => $logGroupName,
            'logStreamName' => $logStreamName,
            'logEvents' => [
                [
                    'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                    'message' => $message
                ],
            ],
            'sequenceToken' => $uploadSequenceToken,
        ]);
    } catch (\InvalidSequenceTokenException $e) {
        $client->putLogEvents([
            'logGroupName' => $logGroupName,
            'logStreamName' => $logStreamName,
            'logEvents' => [
                [
                    'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                    'message' => $message
                ],
            ],
            'sequenceToken' => $e->expectedSequenceToken,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Dose the code above the call to `putLogEvents` need to be in the `try` block?

Comment: Not necessary. The InvalidSequenceTokenException  throw from putLogEvents only.

Answer (score 1):

This is my working solution: before send new putLogEvents you must take the last uploadSequenceToken.

```
    try {
        $client = \Aws\CloudWatchLogs\CloudWatchLogsClient::factory($configCloudWatch);

        $logStreamName = 'testLogStream';
        $logGroupName = 'testGroupName';

        $result = $client->describeLogStreams([
            'logGroupName' => $logGroupName,
            'logStreamNamePrefix' => $logStreamName,
        ]);
        $logStreams=$result->get('logStreams');
        if (!$logStreams)
            throw new \Exception('No log stream found');
        if (count($logStreams)!=1)
            throw new \Exception('Multiple log stream found');
        $uploadSequenceToken = $logStreams[0]['uploadSequenceToken'];

        $client->putLogEvents([
            'logGroupName' => $logGroupName,
            'logStreamName' => $logStreamName,
            'logEvents' => [
                [
                    'timestamp' => round(microtime(true) * 1000),
                    // message is required
                    'message' => json_encode([ ... ]
                    ),
                ],
            ],
            'sequenceToken' => $uploadSequenceToken,
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        \Log::error(__METHOD__, ['exception' => $e]);
    }
```

Comment: Your code may fail in case of mass-concureny access. If several processes call the describeLogStreams() function at (almost) the same time, they will receive different sequenceToken . But only the last receivied is valid. This appends if your Lambda code scale up for example. To prevent this, you have to handle the exception : request a new token if you got an InvalidSequenceTokenException.

Comment: @JayMore this is actually a very good point, and I came to realize this later on. All the Node.js logging packages I used e.g. Pino, Morgan, & Winston suffer from this issue. I am running multiple docker instances for a Node.js app, and sooner or later the logger hits an InvalidSequenceTokenException for this very same reason. While catching the exception and re-invoking the function for a new token works, I'm not sure if it's the best way to go. Could there be other better cost-efficient solutions?